# SQL group by and count by value

Tags: sql, database-design, group-by

I have a database like this:

```
id | name | type | approval
1  |  a   | red  |    0
2  |  b   | blue |   null
3  |  c   | grey |    1
4  |  d   | red  |   null
5  |  e   | blue |    1
6  |  f   | grey |    1
```

And then, I want an output which count every approval value (null: pending, 0: denied, 1: approved) like this:

```
type | pending | denied | approved
red  |    1    |   1    |    0
blue |    1    |   0    |    1
grey |    0    |   0    |    2
```

I am not expert in sql, can I produce an output like this just using sql? if yes, please tell me. And if need some programming language, please tell me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select  type, 
         sum(if(approval is null, 1, 0)) as pending,
         sum(if(approval=0, 1, 0)) as denied,
         sum(if(approval=1, 1, 0)) as approval
   from test
   group by type
```

See it on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9348e/4

And if you want the exact order? add `order by if( type='red', 1 ,if(type='blue',2,3) )`